# How can i setup a dns server on OVH VPS?

Tags: dns, ovh

I have a VPS server on OVH, it just has its own ip and Reverse DNS.
So i basically always used domain trough cloudflare and pointed a record to my VPS IP.

1. I don't want to use cloudflare anymore, I've bought the DNS Anycast option for my domain and pointed a record to my VPS IP, but website just stopped working.. What should i do ?
2. I have 3 more domains, i would want to make some ns1.mydomain.com ns2.mydomain.com zones based on my main domain, so i could use it for all my other domains, How can i do that?

ps. In case if this info is needed, all my domains are in OVH too.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could revert back to previous state. Other than that, it is difficult to troubleshoot DNS issues without real domain name.

2) DNS is crucial part of infrastructure, you don't want to host that by yourself unless you know what you are doing.